# Error referencing RelativeLayout from a Custom Renderer in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-relativelayout

I have a camera custom renderer which's Layout I have developed in FrameView and was working fine until now that, because of the number of objects, I decided to convert it into a RelativeLayout so things didn't scramble with different phone sizes.

The thing is that as soon as I compiled it after the changes, it threw:

> Resource.Id doesn't contain a definition for "every object in the axml file, even if it was *in* the RelativeLayout"

Is it an implementation error?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/SettingsButton"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/Settings"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/UserIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/UserIcon" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggleFlashButton"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/NoFlashButton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchCameraButton"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ToggleCameraButton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takePhotoButton"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/LlamaButton" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Square"
        android:layout_width="275dp" 
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/Square"/> 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>  

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ResultLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/infosquare"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Placeholder"
                android:layout_width="129dp"
                android:layout_height="129dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LlamaPlaceholder"
                android:layout_margin="25dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"/>
              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/WikipediaContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Result"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/WikiButton"
                android:layout_width="146dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/WikipediaContent"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/WikiButton"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Save"
                android:layout_width="291dp"
                android:layout_height="74dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/Save"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ShareButton"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SaveFinding"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/share"/>
        </RelativeLayout> 
</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the actual c# camera Page referencing class:

```
        [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraPage), typeof(CameraPageRenderer))]
    namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
...
 void SetupUserInterface()
        {
            activity = this.Context as Activity;
            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CameraLayout, this, false);
            cameraType = CameraFacing.Back;

            textureView = view.FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
            textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
           
            square = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Square);
            square.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

            resultframe = view.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.ResultFrame);
            resultframe.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

            resultText = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Result);

            Content = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Content);

        }
```

And the same thing happens with the buttons in the "SetupEventHandlers()" class, but you get it ;)

Comment: I didn't see `Resource.Id.ResultFrame`  and `Resource.Id.Content` defined in your xml layout.

Comment: Yes, it slipped me. I don't think there lies the problem, because the other objects can't  be referenced either.

Comment: Did you try to clean the solution and delete the bin and obj file,and rebuid ?